# Shaded surround Boxes with margins

Tags: tcolorbox

How to set shade surround boxes in the left right and bottom margins in tcolorbox, I tried lot of options in tcolorbox using borderline, leftrule, etc. which is not worked to me, please help us how to set as per attached images.(Ignore black highlighted in the bottom of attached image.)[image]

Sorry, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum,textcase,multicol}
\RequirePackage[breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}

\makeatletter
\def\boxthreelabelfont{\noindent\fontsize{17bp}{14bp}\selectfont\bfseries\color{white}}
\def\boxthreetitlefont{\noindent\fontsize{11bp}{14bp}\selectfont\color{white}}
\def\boxthreetextfont{\noindent\fontsize{8.5bp}{11bp}\selectfont\parindent0pt\parskip9pt}
\newenvironment{Boxthree}[2][]{\begingroup\begin{tcolorbox}
[enhanced,breakable,%
arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=1pt,boxsep=0pt,top=22.7pt,left=14.5pt,right=15pt,bottom=5.5pt,middle=0pt,
bottomsep at break=0pt,topsep at break=2pt,
titlerule=0pt,titlerule style={gray,line width=0pt,},toptitle=9.9pt,bottomtitle=9.0pt,lefttitle=22pt,
righttitle=22pt,
title={{\boxthreelabelfont\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}\par\vskip4.5pt{\boxthreetitlefont\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}},
colbacktitle=black,colframe=gray,colback=white,rounded corners=southeast,
fontupper={\boxthreetextfont},
before skip=15pt,after skip=15pt,
toggle enlargement,
grow to left by=15pt,grow to right by=46pt, bottomrule at break=-8pt, toprule at break=-20pt,
arc=15pt,%leftrule=60pt,rightrule=60pt,
overlay={\draw[gray,line width=63pt]
      (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west);}
%borderline={60pt}{20pt}{15black},
%leftrule=60pt
%overlay first={
%\fill[black!15,sharp corners] ([xshift=0pt]65pt,20pt) rectangle ([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west);
%\fill[black!15] (-35mm,-2.5mm) rectangle (145mm,6mm);}
%overlay last={
%\fill[black!15,sharp corners] ([xshift=0pt]65pt,20pt) rectangle ([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west);
%\fill[black!15] (-35mm,-2.5mm) rectangle (145mm,6mm);}
]\null\ignorespaces\removelastskip\vspace{-16.8\p@}\begin{multicols}{2}}{\end{multicols}\end{tcolorbox}\endgroup}

\def\boxtwobreak{\end{multicols}\pagebreak\begin{multicols}{2}}


\begin{document}
 \begin{Boxthree}{Example 1.4}
What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.

 What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.

\boxtwobreak

 What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.
 What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.
\end{Boxthree}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but may be you want a [`drop midday shadow`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=182) (page 185 in v4.20)

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum,textcase,multicol}
\RequirePackage[breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}

\makeatletter
\def\boxthreelabelfont{\noindent\fontsize{17bp}{14bp}\selectfont\bfseries\color{white}}
\def\boxthreetitlefont{\noindent\fontsize{11bp}{14bp}\selectfont\color{white}}
\def\boxthreetextfont{\noindent\fontsize{8.5bp}{11bp}\selectfont\parindent0pt\parskip9pt}
\newenvironment{Boxthree}[2][]{%
\begingroup\begin{tcolorbox}[%
enhanced,breakable,%
%arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, 
boxrule=1pt, boxsep=0pt, top=22.7pt, left=14.5pt, right=15pt, bottom=5.5pt, middle=0pt, bottomsep at break=0pt, topsep at break=2pt, titlerule=0pt, 
titlerule style={gray, line width=0pt,}, 
toptitle=9.9pt, bottomtitle=9.0pt, lefttitle=22pt, righttitle=22pt,title={{\boxthreelabelfont\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
        \par\vskip4.5pt{\boxthreetitlefont\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}},
colbacktitle=black, 
colframe=gray, 
colback=white, rounded corners=southeast,
fontupper={\boxthreetextfont}, before skip=15pt, after skip=15pt,
toggle enlargement, grow to left by=15pt, grow to right by=46pt, bottomrule at break=-8pt, toprule at break=-20pt, 
arc=15pt,
drop midday shadow,
%
%
%leftrule=60pt,rightrule=60pt,
%overlay={\draw[gray,line width=63pt]
%      (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west);}
%borderline={60pt}{20pt}{15black},
%leftrule=60pt
%overlay first={
%\fill[black!15,sharp corners] ([xshift=0pt]65pt,20pt) rectangle ([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west);
%\fill[black!15] (-35mm,-2.5mm) rectangle (145mm,6mm);}
%overlay last={
%\fill[black!15,sharp corners] ([xshift=0pt]65pt,20pt) rectangle ([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west);
%\fill[black!15] (-35mm,-2.5mm) rectangle (145mm,6mm);}
]\null\ignorespaces\removelastskip\vspace{-16.8\p@}\begin{multicols}{2}}{\end{multicols}\end{tcolorbox}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\def\boxtwobreak{\end{multicols}\pagebreak\begin{multicols}{2}}


\begin{document}
 \begin{Boxthree}{Example 1.4}
What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.

 What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.

\boxtwobreak

 What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.
 What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession the legal profession.

What made you decide to be a lawyer? Perhaps someone in your family introduced you to the idea, or you were inspired by a lawyer you had read about in a book or seen on TV or in a movie. Perhaps you had the opportunity to speak to a practising lawyer at some point in your life, or you attended a legal trial. Perhaps you have arrived at law school knowing that you have wanted to be a lawyer your entire~life.
By enrolling in your law degree, you have taken the first step in your journey towards becoming a member of a long-standing and honourable profession  the legal profession.
\end{Boxthree}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I adjusted output provided your idea.